# Is there a way to make shared_ptr.reset(new obj) to call the destructor first?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

In this excample

```
std::shared_ptr<obj> ptr = new obj("old");
ptr.reset(new obj("new"));
```

the constructor of the `obj("new")` will called first, then the destructor of the `obj("old")` will be called.

Is there a way to destruct `obj("old")` first then construct `obj("new")` later? (other than call `ptr.reset()` first then call `ptr.reset(new obj("new"))`)

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: You already mentioned the solution in your last sentence: call `ptr.reset()` first then create the new object and call `reset()` again with this new pointer. That's lets you order things exactly how you want. Why doesn't it work for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure.

```
ptr.reset();
ptr = std::make_shared<obj>("new");
```

this doesn't match your "other than" clause (at least not exactly), and it destroys the old object first.

I can produce pages of variations.

There is no single-function API in `shared_ptr` that first destroys the contents of a shared pointer, then executes some code to construct a replacement.

Answer (score 5):

No way to do it in a single call like `ptr.reset(new obj("new"))`, because the parameter passed to `reset` function will be evaluated before `reset` is entered. Whatever `reset` does, `new obj("new")` will be evaluated first.

So you have to first call `reset()` and then pass a newly created object in a second step.